# java OpenGL lwjgl draw 2D then 3d then 2d, error

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, 2d

I can draw 2D then 3D just fine, but when I draw 2D again, it clears the first 2D.
Here is the 2d (Stars) with 3d
http://postimg.org/image/8lbkbnkgv/

here is what happend when i try and draw a 2D layer affter the 3d
http://postimg.org/image/oiac8dcv3/

```
    public void RenderLoop()
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Draw2d
    glLoadIdentity();
this.init2D();      
    this.Render2DBefore();                
    //Draw2d        

//Draw3d         
    this.init3D();        
    gluLookAt((float)this.myEyeMain.eye.posX, (float)this.myEyeMain.eye.posY, (float)this.myEyeMain.eye.posZ, (float)this.myEyeMain.look.posX, (float)this.myEyeMain.look.posY, (float)this.myEyeMain.look.posZ, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, this.modelview);
    Render();
    //Draw3d


    //Draw2d
    glLoadIdentity();
this.init2DB();      
    this.Render2DAfter();                        
    //Draw2d      


    Display.update();
}
public void init2D()
{
    glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);              
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         
    // enable alpha blending
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();



}
public void init2DB()
{
    glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);              
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         
    // enable alpha blending
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glViewport(0,0,width,height);



    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);


    GL11.glLoadIdentity();



}
public void init3D()
{
    glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(45f, (float) width / (float) height, 1f, this.viewMax);        
    GL11.glGetFloat( GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, this.projection);
    GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, this.viewport);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a couple of questionable things here:

1. You are using `glOrtho (...)` to setup your ModelView matrix
2. You have your Y-axis inverted in `glOrtho (...)`

While 1 is definitely an error that needs to be corrected, 2 is perfectly valid but I want to mention a few things about inverting the Y-axis of your projection matrix.

When you set the point (0,0) to be the top-left corner of your window, if you rely on any part of OpenGL that depends on which side (front / back) of a polygon is being drawn (e.g. face culling, vertex lighting, stencil), they will not work as expected. This projection matrix changes the handedness of your projection, and you will need to re-define the front face from its default: **counter-clockwise** to **clockwise**. Often in 2D this does not matter, but if you enabled back-face culling in your 3D setup and forgot to turn it off it could become a very serious issue.

To correct your `init2D (...)` and `init2DB (...)` functions, re-write the matrix setup code:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode   (GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity ();
GL11.glOrtho        (0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);

GL11.glMatrixMode   (GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity ();
```

Comment: When i change init2d and init2dB to this, the 3d was gone, so I left init2D alone and just change init2DB and everything works now. thanks

Comment: @freethemice: Oh, I did not catch that... there is more to the problem. You also need to add `glLoadIdentity (...)` immediately after you call `glMatrixMode (GL11.GL_PROJECTION)` in `init3D (...)`. You need to setup an identity matrix first, because `gluPerspective (...)` multiplies the "current" matrix by a perspective projection matrix. If you do that, it will fix your problem the right way.

Comment: thank you that works great now, I'm a little confused on the seting up a identity matrix.

Comment: @freethemice: Well, all of the functions like `glOrtho (...)` and `gluPerspective (...)`, `gluLookAt (...)`, etc. multiply what is known as the "current" matrix. OpenGL is a state machine, so from the second you start it up it remembers the state of all of those matrices across every frame. Since you do not want to multiply a perspective matrix by another perspective matrix, for instance, you load an identity matrix to basically clear out the matrix. Multiplying an identity matrix by anything returns the matrix you multiplied, and that is the behavior you actually want in this case.